# Removing default.aspx from the url in ASP.NET 2005

Tags: asp.net, seo, canonical-link

I have a app that is setup on IIS 6.0. We are having trouble with Search Engine optimization with the default.aspx page.
For Example when I type www.xxxxxx.com/default.aspx it should redirect to www.xxxxxx.com.

Can anyone please help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
  public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl == "/default.aspx")
                {
                    Response.StatusCode = 301;
                    Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
                    Response.RedirectLocation = "/";
                    Response.End();
                }
            }
         }
     }
```

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl gives me /foldername/default.aspx regardless of whether i browse to /foldername or /foldername/default.aspx, so that code redirects forever  :(

Comment: @JordanHudson, is it foldername a separate application?

Answer (score 0):

Set the default document in IIS under the Documents tab. Once in the Documents tab, check "Enable default content page" and set Default.aspx as the first item (or only) in the list.